# C - scanf char used for argv in loop

Tags: c

actually struggling with my code in C. I've added some program arguments and I want to print  those beggining with letter user chooses. Glad for any advice.

Thank you

```
**Build messages:**
warning: multi-character character constant
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char firstLetter;

    printf("What city r u looking for?\n");
    scanf("%c", &firstLetter);

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '%c', "firstLetter") { //fault here?
            printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**This one works great:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        if (argv[i][1] == 'r') {
            printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want your loop to begin from 0 instead of 1

Comment: @AmitSingh Why?

Comment: @AmitSingh, in C, when you run an application from the command-line, `argv[0]` is a string containing the executable's filename. Therefore, the first argument passed to the program is actually `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is an issue with placing both an invalid character cosntant and a constant string literal inside of your if statement:

```
if (argv[i][0] == '%c', "firstLetter") //fault here?
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

This if statement's condition has several issues. First, `'%c'` is an invalid statement in general because anything surrounded by single quotes is expected to be a one-character literal. Therefore, `'%c'` would be invalid because it is two characters.

Next, you are comparing `'%c'`, but then you are discarding the result. The comma operator in C is rather useful and surprisingly underused. Within conditional expressions, the comma operator causes everything to the left of it to be ignored, and indicates that only the item(s) to the right of the comma should be considered when evaluating the condition. As an example if you say, `if ( i = i+2, x != 'y' ){ ... }`, then this will actually cause `i` to be incremented by two, then the comma causes the value to be ignored before the `x != 'y'` comparison is evaluated. So, in your case, it might actually be valid to say `if (argv[i][0] == 'c', "firstLetter")`.
 (Although, the result would still not be what you want.) In this case, `argv[i][0] == 'c'` would be evaluated, and then the result of that evaluation would discarded. After that is discarded, `"firstLetter"` would be evaluated for its truthiness. `"firstLetter"` is a truthy value, the condition `if (argv[i][0] == 'c', "firstLetter")` would almost certainly evaluate to true. (Assuming your compiler lets you compile that.)

Focusing on your specific use case, I would venture to guess you wanted to say `if (argv[i][0] == firstLetter)`, which will compare the first letter of the `argv[i]` string against the character stored in the `firstLetter` variable.

Comment: Note that multi-character constants are valid but the value is implementation defined. The standard illustrates with `’ab’`, IIRC.